# Black window after system reboot Ubuntu 20

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, 20.04

Recently, my computer crashed, I could not do anything and decided to restart it through a physical button on my computer. If, when you turn on the GRUB bootloader, choose the usual boot ubuntu, then I see only a black screen. I changed the boot options, removed the graphical display, now I see which processes have been turned on when the system starts. After the entire download list has passed, I again see a black screen. In this case, I can’t even go to the console through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

To enter the system, I have to select the recovery mode in the GRUB. Then the system turns on and I see the interface and can work. However, after the restart, the driver seems to have flown (I'm not sure). My Wi-Fi did not work, the system wrote that there was no adapter (I solved this problem). However, my computer is connected to the TV and now in the settings I can not select it for audio output.

I'm a simple user, so I don't know to solve my problems.

*Processor: AMD FX-8300, Video card :RX-470.*

Please tell me what it is in general and how to solve the problem with loading the system? I suppose here is any other way without reinstalling Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hard reset can sometimes break a system quite badly and damage the file system. You managed to bring your system back to life, but that does not ensure that all damage is repaired.

The most secure way to revert to an integer system would be to fully reinstall, i.e., back up user data, reinstall fresh and put the data back. Second possibility, less sure, it to reinstall a system (should be the same version!) however without reformatting: that refreshes the system files, but keeps the configuration data intact. Such install can be done by selecting "Something else" in the installer. Then you manually assign the partitions the same way they are assigned now, but you make sure that the "Format" checkbox remains unchecked.

*Some advice*

- If you are unsure about the technicalities, just go for a fresh install: that is fundamentally the only secure option to rescue a file system damaged by a power outage, and it is, technically, the easiest.
- Next time you have a hard lock, keep a hard reset for the last. First try if you can get to a virtual console (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3 or higher</kbd>). `poweroff` or `sudo poweroff` from there. In second order, try the famous `reisub` [key sequence](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysrq.html). This procedure gives messages to the kernel, among others to write all caches to the disk and close the disk.